# How would I construct an integer optimization model corresponding to a graph

Tags: modeling

Suppose we're given some sort of graph where the feasible region of our optimization problem is given. For example: here is an image
[image]

How would I go on about constructing these constraints in an integer optimization problem? Anyone got any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Your image really needs more context, it would be helpful if you could describe your non-integer approach to this problem so that people can give constructive advice how your problem could be solved differently.

Comment: @Lucas Basically, I have something like this: Minimize Z = c1x1 + c2x2 (for some c1, c2), s.t. some line equations that only hold when say z=0 or z=1? (to make it integer)

Comment: The question is still unclear to me. From the comments, it looks like you have the LP formulation of the problem and you want to obtain the ILP formulation of it, which seems like a trivial task *(i.e. replace rational variables with integer ones)*. Can you **edit** your question and formalize your problem a bit further? The picture is not needed, unless you are really starting from a picture and nothing else. Try to describe your problem mathematically, if possible. It would also help to know what you tried and why you failed.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, I agree with the others that you should be a little more specific than that paint-ish picture ;). In particular you are neither specifying any objective/objective direction nor are you giving any context, what about this graph should be integer-variable related, except for the existence of disjunctive feasible sets, which may be modeled by MIP-techniques. It seems like your problem is formalization of what you conceptualized. However, in case you are just being lazy and are just interested in modelling disjunctive regions, you should be looking into disjunctive programming techniques, such as "big-M" (Note: big-M reformulations can be problematic). You should be aiming at some convex-hull reformulation if you can attain one (fairly easily).

Back to your picture, it is quite clear that you have a problem in two real dimensions (let's say in R^2), where the constraints bounding the feasible set are linear (the lines making up the feasible polygons).

So you know that you have two dimensions and need two real continuous variables, say `x[1]` and `x[2]`, to formulate each of your linear constraints (`a[i,1]*x[1]+a[i,2]<=rhs[i]` for some index i corresponding to the number of lines in your graph). Additionally your variables seem to be constrained to the first orthant so `x[1]>=0` and `x[2]>=0` should hold. Now, to add disjunctions you want some constraints that only hold when a certain condition is true. Therefore, you can add two binary decision variables, say `y[1],y[2]` and an additional constraint `y[1]+y[2]=1`, to tell that only one set of constraints can be active at the same time. You should be able to implement this with the help of big-M by reformulating the constraints as follows:

If you bound things from above with your line:
`a[i,1]*x[1]+a[i,2]-rhs[i]<=M*(1-y[1])` if i corresponds to the one polygon,
`a[i,1]*x[1]+a[i,2]-rhs[i]<=M*(1-y[2])` if i corresponds to the other polygon,
and if your line bounds things from below:
`-M*(1-y[1])<=-a[i,1]*x[1]-a[i,2]+rhs[i]` if i corresponds to the one polygon,
`-M*(1-y[1])<=-a[i,1]*x[1]-a[i,2]+rhs[i]` if i corresponds to the other polygon.
It is important that M is sufficiently large, but not too large to cause numerical issues.

That being said, I am by no means an expert on these disjunctive programming techniques, so feel free to chime in, add corrections or make things clearer.

Also, a more elaborate question typically yields more elaborate and satisfying answers ;) If you had gone to the effort of making up a true small example problem you likely would have gotten a full formulation of your problem or even an executable piece of code in no time.